# JavaScript - how to grab unique urls from array based on unique #?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to grab unique URLs from this array.

```
var urls = [
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
]
```

From the code, the fifth array are `['791','246','796','051', '056']`, so the output is like this:

```
[
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
]
```

From another answer, I was able to grab just the unique fifth codes in an array:

```
var unique = ['791','246','796', '051','056']
```

Then I tried to do this in order to grab unique URLs and push it to an empty array, but it's not working out.

```
var uniqueUrls = []
for(i=0; i < unique.length; i++){
  for(j=0; j< urls.length; j++){
    if(urls[j].indexOf(unique[i])){
      uniqueUrls.push(urls[j]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me with this? Am I doing something wrong in the for loop? Or is there a better way to grab unique URLs from the URL arrays without using the double for loop?

**update**

Forgot to mention the other digit codes are not always 'zeros', they can be any random number but I'm still interested in grabbing unique urls based on the fifth code.

Comment: 1. `.indexOf(unique[i])` should be `>-1`. 2) why the `break`?

Comment: @mparnisari I added the break so once it finds its, it goes to the next `unique` value.  Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 `Set` with array spread to get unique values:

```js
const getUnique = (urls) => [...new Set(urls.map((url) => url.match(/\/banner\?l_id=(?:\w+-){4}(\w+)/)[1]))];

var urls = [
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
];
  
console.log(getUnique(urls));
```

If you can't use ES6, use reduce with a hash object to check for uniqueness:

```js
function getUnique(urls) {
  var hash = {};
  
  return urls.reduce(function(arr, url)  {
    var id = url.match(/\/banner\?l_id=(?:\w+-){4}(\w+)/)[1];
    
    if(!hash[id]) {
      arr.push(id);
      
      hash[id] = true;
    }
    
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

var urls = [
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
  "http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
];
  
console.log(getUnique(urls));
```

Comment: This is great! I like you used regex, but I forgot to mention that the other codes are not always 'zeros', they can be any random number.  Though I'm still interested in the urls with unique fifth codes.  How can i modify the regex based on what I just mentioned? Not familiar with regex, still learning.

Comment: Is the structure always the same? What will change except for the numbers?

Comment: before `banner?l_id=` stays the same, also after `&k`.  Just in this section `A000-0000-0000000-000000-791`, there are 5 groups of digits.  I get this from a report, I noticed the first four can be any random number, but the fifth one repeats , then it changes to a different # and it repeats again; which is why i'm interested in the fifth code.

Comment: I've update the answer to use the regex suggested by @anubhava in your previous question. It's much more generic, and frankly much better then anything I could come up with :)

Comment: Oh, I realized this returns only the digit, but not the url.  But I could use the double for loop I had. i forgot to add `> -1`, like @mparnisari mentioned.

Comment: Take whatever solution makes you happy, just remember that double loops are usually O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

```
var urls = [
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-791-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-246-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-796-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-051-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk",
"http://display.companyX.com/rest/banner?l_id=A000-0000-0000000-000000-056-0-0-0&k=A77K_fakfhaskfhkjshfkjo=kafkjafk"
];

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var unique = urls.filter(onlyUnique);
```